# MongoDB - how to deserialize collection to List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I'm switching my application from working with SQL Server to MongoDB.
One of the main reason for doing it is the possibility to use structure-less collections.
In my "SQL Version" I had object named `RawSensorMessage` which contained many properties and most of them were empty at most cases. So when I moved into Mongo I changed `RawSensorMessage` definition to the following one:

```
   [DataContract]
    public class RawSensorMessage
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Assume Inside Mongo I have a collection with many records which each one contains different properties.
When I query this collection, I don't want to map it to a strongly type object, I want to query it to a 'RawSensorMessage' object (means to fill the 'Data' dictionary inside with the properties and values).

How should I do it?
Is it accepted approach to work with structure-less collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to cast your BSON document which you get from the MongoDB to an JSON object: [ToJSON()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/8edc0d16-6676-7936-c8d0-05e4192e2c0e.htm) After that you can serialize your JSON object to a dictionary, like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Hope this help.